# How to use read.table to use ^A (ctrl-A) as a field seperator

Tags: r

I have a data file I am trying to load via read.table.  The file has ^A (ctrl-A) as the field separator. 
It looks something like this via vi:

```
5^A41244901564015^A2542435^A2345234
```

My attempts have been:

```
myDf <- read.table(file = "myfile.asv", sep = '^A')

Error in scan(file, what = "", sep = sep, quote = quote, nlines = 1, quiet = TRUE,  : 
  invalid 'sep' value: must be one byte

myDf <- read.table(file = "myfile.asv", sep = as.character('^A'))

Error in scan(file, what = "", sep = sep, quote = quote, nlines = 1, quiet = TRUE,  : 
  invalid 'sep' value: must be one byte
```

Any suggestions on creating a ctrl-A separator for use with read.table?  Is there some alternate solution I should be considering.

Per the comments tried:

> myDf <- read.table(file = "myfile.asv", sep = '\001')

Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
  line 1 did not have 30 elements

Comment: This could be a solution. Although don't think this the idiomatic way to solve  this: `df <- read.table(file = "myfile.asv", sep = "^") ; df[] <- sapply(df, function(x) gsub("^A", "", x))`

Comment: If it is the start of heading control sequence then you could try `"\u2401"` as the unicode equivalent. But if it is a caret (^) followed by a captial A, then this is two separate characters (bytes) and will not work with `read.table`

Comment: I'd suggest to use a fast command line text editor (like sed or awk) to replace the seperators with something more sensible.

Comment: How are you looking at the file and seeing "^A"? If you look at the bytes, are they literally two character "^" and "A"? So if you look at the first three bytes of your data `charToRaw("5^A"....)` do you see `35 5e 41` or something else?

Comment: Looking at the first line of readLines it is ASCII character \001 (^A).  It is not 2 characters.

Comment: So did you try setting `sep=""\001"`? (if you don't use `@` i don't get notified of your response automatically)

Comment: @MrFlick - yes causes a error.  I will update the main question.

Comment: Well, that's a very different type error. What does  `count.fields(file = "myfile.asv", sep = '\001')` return? Do you expect every row to have same number of columns?

Comment: @MrFlick - thanks, I guess I had but changed to fill=T and now it is working.

Answer (score 0):

The `sep` argument must be of just 1 character and so `^A` is not a valid `sep` value. You could work-around by reading all the lines of the file and split them through `strsplit`:

```
    lines<-readLines("file.txt")
    ret<-simplify2array(strsplit(lines,"^A",fixed=TRUE))
```

You may need to transpose (`t` function) the result, assign colnames to it, coerce the individual columns to the proper data type (in this way everything is `character`) and coerce to a `data.frame`.

Otherwise, you can read the entire file through `readChar`, `gsub` the `^A` to a proper separator and the use `read.table`:

```
    fileContent<-readChar("file.txt",nchar=file.info("file.txt")$size)
    fileContent<-gsub("^A",";",fileContent,fixed=TRUE)
    ret<-read.table(text=fileContent,sep=";")
```

Comment: Thanks, gave me more to try. Used readLines - Looking at the first line it is ASCII character \001 (^A). It is not 2 characters.

Comment: The simplify2array code was workable as well, although slow.  Had to use \001 for splitting and did need the transpose after.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all, @MrFlick the proper separator was actually the answer.  I just happened to have some addition artifacts I had to account for in the data.

Final code was:

> myDf <- read.table(file = "myfile.asv", sep = '\001', na.strings ='\\N', quote = "", fill=T)